# How do I configure my own DNS Server?

Tags: dns

Okay. I've been researching for over an hour now and I did not find any useful help. What I'm essentially looking to do is, I want to create a custom DNS Server (just like google has 8.8.8.8, but not that complex).

For example: I could just map facebook.com --> some other IP address and send rest of the DNS traffic through 8.8.8.8. Then, when, in my router page, I change my DNS from 8.8.8.8 to mycustomIPAddress DNS (1.2.3.4 like), and I open facebook.com, it gets mapped to some other IP (say, just a blank page).

How do I do this? How do I get that "mycustomIPAddress DNS" to put into my router? Can anybody provide some sources to read?

Comment: That would depend on the system you want to host the DNS on. For Windows there is a GUI available on Linux you could use bind or something more simple. In either case the configuration could become complex. What are you actually trying to achieve by setting up a private DNS server? After all clients could just use 8.8.8.8 if they chose to, you're aware of that, right?

Comment: @Seth I actually want to map a couple of URLs to custom page. The only access I have right now is the router page (where I can configure Primary DNS IP like 8.8.8.8). I was looking to create such an IP myself where I just map a couple of requests to some other URL and let pass others through 8.8.8.8 or some other DNS.

Comment: This would be done by adding a line for that in the local hosts file (which is basically the DNS that the computer checks before going to the external DNS server (8.8.8.8 in your example)

Comment: @YisroelTech But the only access I have is the DNS IP in router page. I cannot modify hosts file.

Comment: Are you trying to do this for a single host on your network or all machines on your network? Depending on it, it might be easier to set it up using your hosts file. In addition what kind of access to you have to the router? Do you have SSH or similar access? What model is it? Do you have a machine on your network that could serve as a DNS server or are you planning to host it some other way?

Comment: @MehulMohan you can't change settings on the computer? Then I think you should use something like OpenDNS to block what you wanna block (if blocking, as you said "blank page", is what you are looking for). Setting up a DNS server is quite complex and It does not seem that that's what you are looking for

Comment: @Seth I've access to the server and thus the router config page. I'm working on a LAN network. Sure, hosts file is a way, but I also want to learn (if feasible), to create (kinda) a DNS IP address to have my own mappings. Like google.com --> 182.xx.xx.xx; stackoverflow.com --> 179.xx.xx.xx; Is there a way to create such a file, and somehow configure an IP address, which when placed in place of 8.8.8.8, works as I mentioned?

Comment: @YisroelTech Hmm.Just like we do configure hosts file on individual machines like `HOSTNAME: IP ADDR` by cleanly mapping them together, I thought there might be a similar way to pack all/some domain names on internet (haha) and create a DNS IP out of it which I can use somewhere, just like 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: @MehulMohan it is indeed 'possible', and if you're running a Windows server (which I assume you do not) it should probably be on. But as the other folks pointed out it would become complex to do and I simply think it isn't a good solution for you nor is it something you're willing to put in the effort necessary to set it up

Comment: Sounds like you want dnsmasq. However, it needs a (Linux/*BSD) computer/router to run on.

Comment: You do have to have some machine that can host the DNS server. Currently it doesn't look like you have a machine that would be able to. Any kind of PC would do or you could possibly do it on your router, depending on its specs/model and your willingness to possibly replace the OS on it. The answer from david is pretty good in that regard as it has a nice summary. You would need to setup a solution on your network and just let your clients use it but you would have to make a decision on your approach and give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need just override external DNS records then all you need - it some respectful DNS forwarder (I prefer [Unbound](https://unbound.net/download.html)), it works on unix based OS and Windows.

In the config file you can easily override DNS records for any domain you like just with two lines:

```
local-zone: "google.com." redirect
local-data: "google.com.  600 IN A 1.2.3.4"
```

To apply your changes to the whole LAN network, you need to run it on your root router that should support to run custom/additional software, so any clients on the network would use your rules.
Do not forget that if some one on your local network know IT stuff, they can manually set up their own preferences on their machines.
If it is a case then you need a decent firewall/router (Something like [PFsense](https://pfsense.org/) that have all you need) that can block outgoing connections to 53 port (DNS queries), so the only choice for your users would be to use your DNS. (Well, they can still tunnel their traffic, you can actually protect against it, but it out of scope of this thread)